# Vue 3 Teleport for Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-teleport

In Vue 3 it's possible to [Teleport](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/teleport.html#using-with-vue-components) a component to the `body` tag like so:

```
<template>
  <button @click="modalOpen = true">
    Open full screen modal! (With teleport!)
  </button>
    
  <teleport to="body">
    <div v-if="modalOpen" class="modal">
      <div>
        I'm a teleported modal! 
        (My parent is "body")
        <button @click="modalOpen = false">
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </teleport>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return { 
      modalOpen: false
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This causes the modal dialogue above to be rendered in the `body` tag. How can I achieve a similar thing in Vue 2?

Answer (score 20):

Because Vue 2 doesn't support teleports, I recommend to use [portal-vue](https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue) component made for vue 2 :

**Installation :**

```
npm i portal-vue --save
```

**Usage :**

main.js

```
import Vue from "vue"
import PortalVue from 'portal-vue'
Vue.use(PortalVue)
...
```

inside some child component :

```
<portal to="destination">
  <p>This slot content will be rendered wherever the <portal-target> with name 'destination'
    is  located.</p>
</portal>
```

in other place  :

```
<portal-target name="destination">
  <!--
  This component can be located anywhere in your App.
  The slot content of the above portal component will be rendered here.
  -->
</portal-target
```

Comment: For vue 2 you'll need `npm i portal-vue@2.1.7 --save`

Comment: I prefer [vue2-teleport](https://github.com/Mechazawa/vue2-teleport). You can use any selector as target, just like in vue3. No need for "portal-target".